# C++ Windows using libharu - HPDF_Doc undefined

Tags: libharu

I spent the better part of a full day yesterday trying to get libharu built so that I could use it in my project. After fighting with it, I was finally able to get *zlib*, *libpng* & *libharu* built successfully with no errors.

Now, in my project, I'm trying to implement the libharu to see if it works with a simple bit of code form an example I've found on the inet. However, for some reason I'm getting the error mentioned in the title:
***identifier "HPDF_Doc" is undefined***

All of my *#include* files are present, and there are no other indications that anything is missing. I'm wondering why I'm not able to utilize portions of the libharu while other portions seem to not throw any errors.

Has anybody had experience with certain calls not working with libharu?
I know there are tons of questions about libharu, and I have read through many different threads, questions, examples, etc. but nothing seems to be a fix for my issue.

```
HPDF_Doc pdf;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It would appear as though I've resolved this issue...

Apparently I had my DLL def in the wrong place. Once I moved it, the undefined error went away.

```
#define HPDF_DLL
```

^this is now in the correct spot in my file.

However, now the darn thing is throwing 22 unresolved external errors... I swear this is such a headache it is about to not be worth the time anymore.

C/C++... always having to reinvent the wheel to do something so simple in nature.